# Using mutate on every second row

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to change the following line of code:

```
dat %>% mutate(New = Measurement -lag(Measurement))
```

that computes *measurement(t) - measurement(t-1)* for every row into *measurement(t) - measurement(t-2)* for every second row (others can be set to NA), using the dplyr paradigm.

How can I do that all at once? Is there a more convenient way than doing the following?

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(New = Measurement - lag(Measurement, 2))
dat[which((1:nrow(dat) %% 2) == 0), "New"] <- NA
```

Comment: can you share some of your `dat`?

Comment: `dat %>% mutate(New = ifelse((row_number() %% 2) == 1, Measurement - lag(Measurement, 2), NA))`?

Comment: @Axeman Thanks!!! :-)